# Rotate Element Within H2

Tags: css, rotation

Im trying to rotate a `<span>` within an `<h2>` 90 degrees.

right now if I just set it to rotate nothing happens - but if I add a `display:block` to the `span` then it rotates. My problem is it pushes the rest of the `h2` on to the next line.

Is there any way to have the `h2` display on one line with the `span` rotated in middle of it?

here's how it should look
[image]

**HTML:**

```
<h2>Join <span class="flip-text">With</span><span class="flip-text">Your</span> Family</h2>
```

**CSS:**

```
span.flip-text{font-size:10px; -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg); -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg); -o-transform: rotate(-90deg); filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3); -ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);}
```

Comment: You can try display:inline-block

Comment: that pushes 'family' onto the next line because of the block

Comment: Can you wrap both "With" & "Your" in a single span and try that?

Comment: that just lines up 'with your' in one line on an angle

Answer (score 3):

Just like Christopher was suggesting, display: inline-block is the way to go:
http://jsfiddle.net/X85b6/

```
<h2>Join<span>with<br />your</span>Family</h2>

h2 {
    font-size: 60px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
h2 span {
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 16px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 5px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
    -ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
}
```

Comment: my problem is that the element holding the `h2` (`article`) width is 282px so the 'padding' on the right and left of it is pushing the next word on to the next line

Comment: this is what im getting - [http://i.imgur.com/kPEpGzG.jpg](http://i.imgur.com/kPEpGzG.jpg)

Comment: This is not ideal, since it will force content outside of it's wrapper, but you can add white-space: nowrap; to the <h2>. http://jsfiddle.net/X85b6/1/ What I would suggest is looking at why the article is a set dimension and possibly providing alternate styles for when it's too small to handle the full size design.

Comment: Based on your link, it looks like you need to set left/right padding of the <h2> to 0 and to adjust the line-height of the rotated span.

Comment: the nowrap method is gonna mess with it too much - the reason article has a set width is that theres 3 of them lined up on the page.

Comment: What i ended up doing in my case was add margin -15px to the span and that made the space less. it isnt a great fix but it works for now